# Game Stability Issues on PS3?

Tags: ps3, technical-issues, fuel

I own the Xbox 360 port of *FUEL*, and have never had any problems with it.  However, someone else in my family owns the PS3 version of the game, and has had various issues with running the game.  I find it odd that this version of the game would have these issues, considering it was originally developed for the PS3.

---

Some of the more prominent issues:

- Audio/video cutting out.
- Crashing. (This usually happens while driving a very large distance, but not always)
- When driving at very high speeds on the highway, you seem to slowly overtake the graphic drawing speed.  The scenery can't seem to keep up with you, and things start to only be rendered a short distance in front of you.

---

Are these known issues with the game on PS3?  If so, is there anything we can do to combat them?

Answer (score 1):

The graphics problem is common to PS3 because of the difficulty of programming for the cell processor. In general it is considered easier to program for the 360. Nothing you can do about it.

Also makes sure you TV is suitable for gaming, specifically look for a "gaming mode."

Comment: Are these processor issues also linked to the game crashes we've been experiencing?

Comment: The game crashing is due to problems within the code, the processor is not to blame but rather the code. The code can be buggy due to the difficulty of programming for the processor.